# Find smallest number in calculated field

Tags: vba, ms-access

In a MSAccess report, I have fields like:  CurrentHours, Insp1DueTime, Insp2DueTime...Inspn3DueTime, etc. I want a calculated field which outputs the smallest value of (Insp1DueTime-CurrentHours), (Insp2DueTime-Currenthours), (Insp3DueTime-CurrentHours), etc.

Is there a VBA command which will do this, similar to '*smallestvalue*'((currenthours-insp1duetime), (Currenthours-insp2duetime),...(currenthour-InspnDueTime))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, but you can make one really easily, using a `ParamArray`:

```
Public Function SmallestValue(ParamArray Values())
    Dim Value
    For Each Value In Values
        If IsEmpty(SmallestValue) Or SmallestValue > Value Then
            SmallestValue = Value
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

A paramarray takes any input, and puts it into an array. You iterate over that array, and test if things are larger or smaller.

This works with any input, e.g.: `SmallestValue(2,1,3,4)` returns `1`, `SmallestValue(Now(), Date(), #1/1/2001#)` returns `#1/1/2001#`, `SmallestValue("banana", "apple", "pear")` returns `"apple"`